# setTimeout not working properly with ajaxStart

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, settimeout

I want to delay the appearance of my loading gif during the execution of an ajax request so that it doesn't show up if the request doesn't last more than a second. Even though the gif shows up without adding a big delay, when I set the value more than 80 in the setTimout function, it just doesn't. What am I missing?

```
function ajaxLoading()
{
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () 
    {
        ajaxLoadingTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            $('#loading').show();
        }, 1000)

    });

    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        clearTimeout(ajaxLoadingTimeout);
        $('#loading').hide();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function ajaxLoading()
{    
    var flag=true;
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () 
    {
        flag=true;
        ajaxLoadingTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            if(flag){
               $('#loading').show();
            }
        }, 1000)

    });

    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        flag=false;
        clearTimeout(ajaxLoadingTimeout);
        $('#loading').hide();
    });
}
```

Comment: I already checked this and many other ways that people suggest in other posts but unfortunatelly the same thing happens. It only works for a max value of 80. There must be something else that stops it from executing.

Comment: This logic need to work because if ajax call stop before 1 sec then that flag set to false.

Comment: I know and I double checked it just to make sure. It still works for values < 84. For some reason it doesn't work for values > 83.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that there are 3 ajax requests in a row. First one is triggered but during the delay that has been set the next one starts, not triggering the ajaxStart this time since the last one hasn't finished yet.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer based on comment**

```
function ajaxLoading()
{
    $('document')
    .ajaxStart(function(){
        $("#loading").delay(1000).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function(){
        $("#loading").hide();
        $(this).unbind("ajaxStart");
    });
}
```

Comment: I want the loading gif to be delayed for 1 second so that it won't show up if the ajax request lasts less than 1 second. I only want the gif to show up when the request last more than 1 second.

Comment: u can set delay for 1 second then load div $("#loading").delay(1000).show(); answer updated

Comment: According to the jQuery documentation only subsequent events in a queue are delayed; for example this will not delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which do not use the effects queue. I'm trying to use .fadeIn(400) instead of the show() function but somehow it gets triggered only after the request is finished.